Next14 Server action is not executed from a form submission
As of NextJs doc:

Behind the scenes, actions use the POST method, and only this HTTP
method can invoke them.

When I submit my form with:
<form 
  action={customOnFormData}
>

my code:
const customOnFormData = async (formData: FormData) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));

    const userId = user.id;
    const companyId = user.company?.id;

    console.log("executed")
    
    const result = await onCompanyForm(formData, { userId, companyId });
    
    console.log("not executed")

    dispatch(setLoading(false));

my terminal displays:

GET /formulaire-profil?_rsc=1qxp0 200 in 1340ms

Is my server action not executer because the form submission creates a GET, instead of a POST ? And why would it create a GET instead, other forms made the same way work well.
Thank you

have you included use-server directive

yes the server action onCompanyForm is imported from a "use server" file
